# How to merge two images in openCv(python)?

Tags: python, opencv, pyqt5

[I  extracted Red channel at this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BRWq.png)

[and I  created a rectangle for this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8hVG.png)

I want to blending as merge this two images and  withoutRedChannel is should be positioned inside the rectangle

it is for extract red channel:

```
 withoutRedChannel=Pozisyonlama[:,:,2]
```

it is for rectangle:

```
    img_rect = cv2.rectangle(image, pt1, pt2, recColor, thickness, lineType)   
   
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    image = QImage(frame, frame.shape[1],frame.shape[0],frame.strides[0],QImage.Format_RGB888)
```

my function's full code here:

```
  def setRectangleRedChannel(self,_image):
    lineType = cv2.LINE_4
    
    pt1 = (0,45)
    pt2 = (320, 135)
    recColor = (200, 0, 0)
    thickness = 2
    
    x, y = pt1[0], pt1[1]
    w, h = pt2[0] - pt1[0], pt2[1] - pt1[1]
   
    
    image = cv2.resize(_image,(320,180))
    
    Pozisyonlama = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    
    
    
    
    
    withoutRedChannel=Pozisyonlama[:,:,2]
    
    cv2.imshow("",withoutRedChannel)
    
  
    
    #dst = cv2.addWeighted(image.img, 1, withoutRedChannel.img, 1, 0.0)

    
    
  
  
    
    
    
    
    
   
   
    
    
    img_rect = cv2.rectangle(image, pt1, pt2, recColor, thickness, lineType)   
   
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    image = QImage(frame, frame.shape[1],frame.shape[0],frame.strides[0],QImage.Format_RGB888)
    
    
    self.redChannel_image.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image))
```

Comment: Can you please include all of your code, not just one function? This is impossible for me to load up and fix; also the images look like screenshots. Can you host the actual files?

Comment: Blend *how*? There are are uncountable ways of "merging" two images.

Comment: please review: [ask], [mre]

Comment: I uploaded full code

Comment: MRE means "full code" **excluding** parts that aren't affecting the issue

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to merge two images into one, you can do this:

```
img[y_min:y_max,x_min:x_max] = template
```

where `img` is your full image and `template` is the cropped image. Be sure that both images have the same channels.

If your `template` image is in gray scale, you have to do this before to merged with the full image:

```
h, w = template
templateColor = numpy.zeros((h,w,3),numpy.uint8)
for j in range(h):
    for i in range(w):
        templateColor [j,i,:] = template[j,i]
```

For your code, will be:

```
def setRectangleRedChannel(_image):
    lineType = cv2.LINE_4
    pt1 = (0,45)
    pt2 = (320, 135)
    recColor = (200, 0, 0)
    thickness = 2
    x, y = pt1[0], pt1[1]
    w, h = pt2[0] - pt1[0], pt2[1] - pt1[1]
    image = cv2.resize(_image,(320,180))
    withoutRedChannel = image[y:y+h, x:x+w,2]
    color = numpy.zeros((h,w,3),numpy.uint8)
    for j in range(h):
        for i in range(w):
            color[j,i,:] = withoutRedChannel[j,i]
    image[y:y+h, x:x+w] = color[:,:,:]
    cv2.imshow("",image)
```

Comment: gives an error message   ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (90,320) into shape (90,320,3)

Comment: i did it this way  :      withoutRedChannel=Pozisyonlama[:,:,2]
        print(withoutRedChannel)
        #efektli resim
        cv2.imshow("",withoutRedChannel)
        
        h, w = image
        templateColor = np.zeros((h,w,3),np.uint8)
        templateColor[:,:,:] = image[:,:]
        templateColor[45:135,0:320] = withoutRedChannel
     it is gives error:  ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: in your code, withoutRedChannel is the template image

Comment: i did it this way now:  withoutRedChannel=Pozisyonlama[:,:,2]
        print(withoutRedChannel)
        #efektli resim
        cv2.imshow("",withoutRedChannel)
        
        h, w = withoutRedChannel
        templateColor = np.zeros((h,w,3),np.uint8)
        templateColor[:,:,:] = withoutRedChannel[:,:]
        image[45:135,0:320] = templateColor
       
        gives same error